# Splitting one muliple point layer to many layers of one point in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, split-by-attribute

I need to do a cost distance calculation on multiple points in a layer. If I am not mistaken, in order for the calculation to be done on every point separately, I need to run the calculation separately.

How can I divide the original point layer into many one point layers which will be placed in a geodatabase and used for calculation in a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ArcGIS 10.5 and above, you can use the [Split By Attribute](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm) tool which will split each point based on unique attributes:

> Splits an input dataset by unique attributes.

If you have an older version of ArcGIS, you need to select each point manually and export. Or better, you can create your own script and loop over each point to save it to a separate feature class.